# Read multiple RSS feeds

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7

I'm currently trying to create a little RSS reader application on Windows Phone 7.

So far I'm able to display single feeds on different Panoramas and it works fine.

However on my MainPage I want to display the most recent news coming from multiple RSS feeds.

For example I have feed1, feed2 on different pages, and I'd like to show the title of the most recent news coming from both feed1 and feed2 (or more) on my homepage.

Here is the code I've been using for my single feeds

Mainpage_Loaded:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("feed-goes-here"));
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
```

And then :

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error != null) return;

            XElement xmlItems = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            listBox1.ItemsSource = from x in xmlItems.Descendants("item")
                                   where x.Element("enclosure") != null && x.Element("description") != null
                                   select new RSSitem 
                                   {
                                       Description = x.Element("description").Value.Substring(0,100)+"...", 
                                       Title = x.Element("title").Value,
                                       ImageSource = x.Element("enclosure").FirstAttribute.Value 
                                   };

        }
```

I've been testing a lot of methods to solve my problem but still couldn't find the answer.

So my question is : How do i display on a listbox, the most recent news from 2 different feeds on the same page ?
Thank you for your help and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend adding a Date property to RSSItem:

```
public class RSSItem
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

This way, when you download your two RSS feeds, you can weave them together and sort by date:

```
private IEnumerable<RSSItem> Weave(List<RSSItem> feed1, List<RSSItem> feed2)
{
    return feed1.Concat(feed2)
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)
        .Take(10); // Grab the ten most recent entries
}
```

Usage:

```
using System.Linq; // Don't forget to add using statement for System.Linq

public class RssReader
{
    private List<IEnumerable<RSSItem>> _feeds = new List<IEnumerable<RSSItem>>();

    public void Download()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += this.FeedDownloaded;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("feed-goes-here"));
    }

    private void FeedDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) return;

        var xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
        var feed = from x in xml.Descendants("item")
                   where x.Element("enclosure") != null && x.Element("description") != null
                   select new RSSItem()
                   {
                       Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("date").Value),
                       Title = x.Element("title").Value,
                       ImageSource = x.Element("enclosure").FirstAttribute.Value
                   };

        _feeds.Add(feed);

        if (_feeds.Count == 2)
        {
            var result = this.Weave(_feeds[0], _feeds[1]);

            // Assign result to the list box's ItemSource
            // Or better, use data binding.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines the two feeds, sorts them by date, and returns the ten most recent entries.
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<RSSItem> Weave(IEnumerable<RSSItem> feed1, IEnumerable<RSSItem> feed2)
    {
        return feed1.Concat(feed2)
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)
            .Take(10);
    }
}
```